# Getting exception "javax.jms.JMSException: No uris available to connect to" while sending message to queue using Apache camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, message-queue

Writing a broker URL discovery where a service fetches the broker info from the DB ,creates broker URL and then sends the message to the queue using camel route.

The broker URL is as follows-

```
failover:(tcp://server1.com:61616,tcp://server2:61616)?maxReconnectAttempts=0&maxReconnectDelay=120000
```

However getting the following **exception**-

> Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested
>   exception is **javax.jms.JMSException: No uris available to connect
>   to**. (threadID:117)
>   org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized
>   exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is
>   javax.jms.JMSException: No uris available to connect to.
>                   at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
>                   at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
>                   at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
>                   at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:171)
>                   at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:402)

Comment: Are you able to ping server1.com & server2.com and are you able telnet to 61616 port from the client machine where you are getting the above exception?

Comment: How do you build dynamic uris? Do you use receipient list for that http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Issue was resolved. The call to populate URIs was not being called.